# Python Django : item title does not show

Tags: python, django

I've been working todo application. I get itemsfrom db and do for loop with button which can delete each item in the main.html. I just found that text does not shows but only button shows. Now I have 5 items and there are 5 buttons so I guess it does work, but I wander why item's title and writer does not shows.

models.py

```
  from datetime import datetime
  from django.db import models

  class Article(models.Model):
     no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     content = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     is_visible = models.BooleanField()
      created_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    items = Article.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'items': items})
```

home.html

```
{% for title in items %}
<div class="item-block">
<p class="item">{{ item.title }} | {{ item.writer }}</p>
<form action="{% url 'blog:delete' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}">
<button class="submit-button btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">삭제</button></p>
</form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop variable name is `'title'` (which is oddly chosen):

```
{% for title in items %}
```

But you seem to access it as `'item'`: `{{ item.title }}`, `{{ item.writer }}`, etc.! Change the loop variable name to `item`:

```
{% for item in items %}
```